# Реализация системы "перевода" денег между счетами PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

я совершенно не представляю себе как можно реализовать систему перевода денег между аккаунтами. Помогите, ниже представлю все необходимые данные.
Связь с базой данных имеется.

```html
<form method='POST' action='main.php'>
  <input type='text' name='name' class='cabinet_inputs' placeholder='Ник пользователя'>
  <input type='number' name='callprice' class='cabinet_inputs' placeholder='Введите сумму'>
 <button type='button' class='cabinet_buttons'>Передать</button>
</form>
```

На основе этих данных у меня должен выполняться запрос в базу данных "database" в таблицу "users". Колонка с никами "name", с балансом "money".

Необходимо реализовать списание суммы денег с счёта отправителя и добавить к балансу получателя эту самую сумму, спасибо!

Comment: начинаете транзакцию. даете update одному пользователю с минусом, второму с плюсом. В условиях update так же проверяете что бы сумма не стала отрицательной. Т.е. что бы update ничего не изменил, если сумма в минус уйдет. Если обе строки успешно обновлены делаете commit, иначе rollback

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю вас)

Comment: @Mike Зачем транзакция? всё делается в один запрос, а он сам себе транзакция.